# Экспорт данных из phpMyAdmin в Excel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Как взять все данные из таблицы в БД и отправить их в Excel (сделать отчет)?

Comment: Опишите задачу более подробно... а то, может, экспорта в "CSV for Excel" будет достаточно...

Comment: Надо данные из таблицы student перенести в excel, чтобы в дальнейшем в excelе менять данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `phpMyAdmin`:

- Перейдите на вкладку `Export` (при просмотре требуемой таблицы)
- Определитесь с `методом экспорта`, например `Быстрый`
- Выберите в выпадающем меню `Формат` -  `CSV for MS Excel`
- Нажмите на кнопку `Вперед` и выберите место сохранения файла
- Откройте файл с помощью `Excel`

Comment: о спс) заработало